# R st_join return polygon with point attributes

Tags: r, r-sf

Let's say I have the below data along with the code. The code returns `point` data but I want a `polygon`.

How can I do a `spatial join` such that it returns a `polygon` with both the `point` and `polygon` attributes? (Basically, the data will be matched/joined based on the points that fall with in the polygon)

Code + Data

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# Sample poly
poly =  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

# Sample points
pts = data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                  x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                  y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(poly)) 

# Spatial join and output a polygon with the joined attributes, stuck here....
cities_with_counties = st_join(pts,
                                poly)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry type returned by `sf::st_join()` is driven by the functions first argument.

Consider flipping the two - `st_join(poly, pts)`.

The difference in output should be only in geometry type (and ordering of columns).